# Migrate JIve/Aurea Intranet Documents and Attacments - Urgent!

Tags: migration

Desperately need to migrate about 3000 Jive Documents and attachments from Jive Cloud Jive SBS 3007.9.0.0 to SharePoint 365 Online.

Looked everywhere to find native connectors to do it, or documented processes and cannot find anything. I am aware I could use 3rd party services like ThreeWill but the cost is a non-starter for our small company.

Tried to make a PowerAutomate flow with Jive API, but was not successful.

Would really love to hear anyone who's done it on their own and might be willing to share their steps.

I don't care about likes and comments, simply just want all the documents and related attachments.

Thank you so much in advance.